# Creating pandas dataframe from a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. list:

```
list_vals = ['col_a col_B col_C', '12.0 34.0 10.0', '15.0 111.0 23']
```

How can I convert it into a pandas dataframe?

I can start like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_vals[0].split())
```

Is there a way to populate rest of dataframe?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use `io.StringIO` to feed a string into `read_csv`:

```
In [23]: pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(list_vals)), delim_whitespace=True)
Out[23]: 
   col_a  col_B  col_C
0   12.0   34.0   10.0
1   15.0  111.0   23.0
```

This has the advantage that it automatically does the type interpretation that pandas would do if you were reading an ordinary csv-- the columns are floats:

```
In [24]: _.dtypes
Out[24]: 
col_a    float64
col_B    float64
col_C    float64
dtype: object
```

While you could just feed your list into the DataFrame constructor directly, everything would stay strings:

```
In [21]: pd.DataFrame(columns=list_vals[0].split(), 
                      data=[row.split() for row in list_vals[1:]])
Out[21]: 
  col_a  col_B col_C
0  12.0   34.0  10.0
1  15.0  111.0    23

In [22]: _.dtypes
Out[22]: 
col_a    object
col_B    object
col_C    object
dtype: object
```

We could add `dtype=float` to fix this, of course, but we might have mixed types, which the `read_csv` approach would handle in the usual way and here we'd have to do manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by converting to your data to dict, e.g.:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({a: b for a, *b in (zip(*map(str.split, list_vals)))})
   col_B col_C col_a
0   34.0  10.0  12.0
1  111.0    23  15.0
```

Or with your original order:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({a: b for a, *b in (zip(*map(str.split, list_vals)))},
...              columns=list_vals[0].split())
  col_a  col_B col_C
0  12.0   34.0  10.0
1  15.0  111.0    23
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read this as a [numpy structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.rec.html), then pass it over to pandas. This is useful if you also need to work with numpy, and have the data types defined before reading (otherwise numpy is a step back to work with compared to pandas).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

list_vals = ['col_a col_B col_C', '12.0 34.0 10.0', '15.0 111.0 23']

# Gather names from first line, assume all column types are 'd' (i.e. float)
list_dtype = np.dtype([(name, 'd') for name in list_vals[0].split()])

# Create a numpy structured array
ar = np.fromiter((tuple(x.split()) for x in list_vals[1:]), dtype=list_dtype)

# Now convert it to a pandas DataFrame
dat = pd.DataFrame(ar)
```